# Colorize ls-output by filetype

Tags: linux, bash, colors, ls

Every once in a while I have to list some files (~20-50) in Bash on Linux || Mac.
These files are from four different file types.

```
ls nand2tetris/myChips/  
And16.**hdl** And16.**cmp**    And16.**tst**    And16.**out**  
....
```

Is it possible to colorize every file type in a different color, without changing the formatting? I still want to have the standard `ls` multi column, multi row output, not the kind of formatting that `ls -l` presents.

If the solution to the problem is a different technique from distribution to distribution, it would be nice to collect as many solutions as possible in this thread.

Comment: Is this something that LS_COLORS (https://softwaregravy.wordpress.com/2010/10/16/ls-colors-for-mac/) doesn't do? Reading your question it seems like all you need to to define colors for your file types in the LS_COLOR environment variable. I haven't personally noticed an ls which didn't support this for quite some time, but I'm sure there are variations that do not do this.

Answer (score 0):

I have never been in need of do it, but you might want to read [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/19221), I think that it answers your question.